# mmcli can't find modem on Dell Latitude 5401

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, modem

`mmcli` can't find any modem on my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.02.

```
lb01548:~$ sudo mmcli --scan-modems 
successfully requested to scan devices
apastuchov@lb01548:~$ sudo mmcli --list-modems 
No modems were found
```

If I understand the [Dell Latitude 5401 documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/de-de/latitude-14-5401-laptop/latitude_5401_setupspecs/mobiles-breitband?guid=guid-b1cb5ea4-1b5d-4e85-8719-a570dfa599f9&lang=de-de) correctly, the laptop is shipped with Intel XMM 7360 Global LTE modem.
But neither `lspci`

```
$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 0d)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0d)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a30e (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
03:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
39:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6340 Thunderbolt 3 USB 3.1 Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 2C 2016] (rev 02)
3a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3b:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5410 (rev 01)
```

nor `lsusb` list it

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 013: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 012: ID 0bda:0413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 011: ID 0bda:0487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 413c:b06e Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 413c:b06f Dell Computer Corp. Dell dock
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0bda:402e Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bda:5413 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0bda:5487 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Dell dock
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:565c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5843 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does that mean there is no modem on my laptop?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: @chili555 `lsusb` doesn't show the modem also.

Comment: You can try to determine the answer by yourself by: a) looking full model number on laptop to understand its hardware configuration; b) locate SIM slot on laptop (see [page 9](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/latitude-14-5401-laptop_owners-manual_de.pdf) in guide); c) non-destructive laptop disassembly to locate possible LTE modem (see [review](https://laptopmedia.com/review/dell-latitude-5401-review-business-notebook-that-packs-a-punch/), WWAN on [image](https://i2.wp.com/laptopmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/internals-9.jpg?ssl=1)) option.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @N0rbert
Indeed, I've got the answer by myself by following c) approach. There is no [modem](https://www.dell.com/de-de/shop/intel-xmm-7360-lte-advanced/apd/555-bfko/netzwerkl%C3%B6sungen) inside laptop.

Comment: I wrote  my last comment as answer to provide a solution for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to determine the answer by yourself by:

a) looking full model number on laptop to understand its hardware configuration;
b) locate SIM slot on laptop (see [page 9](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/latitude-14-5401-laptop_owners-manual_de.pdf) in guide);
c) non-destructive laptop disassembly to locate possible LTE modem (see [review](https://laptopmedia.com/review/dell-latitude-5401-review-business-notebook-that-packs-a-punch/), WWAN on [image](https://i2.wp.com/laptopmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/internals-9.jpg?ssl=1)) option.